# SQL Server - 4 hr rolling window check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm a newbie to all things SQL and searched for an answer before posting. I have the following code which checks for applications in a webpage and covers the last 24 hrs. I need to change it so it checks for the last 4 hrs (rolling window) everytime it runs (hourly). Please advise. Tried adding some variables to restrict the final output but it did just that, give me the last 4 hrs while still checking the full 24 hr window. Changing the variables at the beginning of the code only makes it update whichever hrs are defined but still checking a 24 hr window.

```
/*Purpose: Run an hourly check of app counts*/

set nocount on

/* Housekeeping and Local Variable declarations
*/
declare @from datetime = DATEADD(hour,-29,GETDATE());
declare @to datetime   = DATEADD(hour,-5,GETDATE());

create table #numbers (Number int, Day int, Applications int);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (0,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (1,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (2,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (3,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (4,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (5,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (6,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (7,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (8,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (9,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (10,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (11,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (12,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (13,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (14,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (15,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (16,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (17,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (18,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (19,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (20,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (21,0,0);    
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (22,0,0);
Insert into #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) Values (23,0,0);

select count(distinct appl_no) as Applications,
datepart(day,ApplicationDate) as day,
datepart(hour,ApplicationDate) as hour
into #records
from apps_table
where ApplicationDate >= @from and ApplicationDate <= @To 
group by datepart(day,ApplicationDate), datepart(hour,ApplicationDate) 
order by datepart(day,ApplicationDate),datepart(hour,ApplicationDate)

;

update #numbers 
set applications= rec.applications, day=rec.day
from #records rec
where Number = rec.hour
;

select *
from #numbers


drop table #records;
drop table #numbers;


/* Final Housekeeping
*/


set nocount off
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm running SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Thanks for sample data,can you also post expected result and actual result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question, I think you just need to change the values ofr the `@From` and `@To` variables:

```
declare @from datetime = DATEADD(hour,-4,GETDATE());
declare @to datetime   = GETDATE();
```

I think I understand the question better now.
Try this instead:

```
/*Purpose: Run an hourly check of app counts*/

set nocount on

/* Housekeeping and Local Variable declarations
*/
declare @from datetime = DATEADD(hour,-4,GETDATE());
declare @to datetime   = GETDATE();


select count(distinct appl_no) as Applications,
datepart(day,ApplicationDate) as day,
datepart(hour,ApplicationDate) as hour
into #records
from apps_table
where ApplicationDate >= @from and ApplicationDate <= @To 
group by datepart(day,ApplicationDate), datepart(hour,ApplicationDate) 
order by datepart(day,ApplicationDate),datepart(hour,ApplicationDate)

;

SELECT INTO #numbers (Number, Day, Applications) 
set rec, applications, day
from #records;

select *
from #numbers


drop table #records;
drop table #numbers;


/* Final Housekeeping
*/


set nocount off
```

Comment: Thank you Zohar, that did it! Appreciate the help so much.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)